# SourceTree/Git Wants to Re-Add All Files

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I apologize if this question has already been answered, but, I can't be sure any solutions line up exactly.

Anyway, I've been humming along for months now just fine using SourceTree with a Bitbucket account.  Now, all of a sudden, when I make a change and SourceTree picks it up, it actually wants to to "re-add" every single file in the project, from .gitignore to the .project file to all the source files and everything in between (I mean "re-add" as in "there's a green circle with a plus in it" in SourceTree).

Needless to say this has me a bit freaked out and while I'm relatively comfortable using Git, I don't want to chance anything here.

Anyone have any ideas?  I didn't do anything out of the ordinary (as far as I know) between the last change and this new change.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the files have exactly the same binary content then this shouldn't affect anything. The files should be the same hash with the result that the content will be too.

You might have had an issue with timestamps; sometimes these can be unreliable. Or something might have touched every file with a new timestamp, which can throw off the method sometimes. If you're running on Windows you might want to set `git core.trustctime false` to disable the timestamp check.

Comment: I'm running this on a Macbook.  Should I check the timestamps on the files themselves?  Anything else I can do on a Mac?

Comment: If you do a 'git add -A' then it will resync the content. You can find out if it's actually going to change anything by doing `git ls-tree HEAD` and compare the output with `git ls-files -s` to see if the same hashes are present. If they are, there won't be a change.

Comment: I've done this and all hashes are there except one: git ls-tree HEAD shows a tree "src", but the other call does not show that hash, and I find that a bit weird/scary. Although oddly enough, git status doesn't show any of those files that SourceTree does.  Really confused.

Comment: FWIW, CLI git is working just fine and doesn't see any of those oddities.  So, for now at least, I can workaround SourceTree by doing it commando line styles.

Comment: If you do a `git status` does it show that the `src` directory as being deleted? It looks like it's no longer considered to be in the index any more. If you do `git add src` it may fix the problem.

Comment: Doing the "git status" doesn't show 'src' as being deleted, and if i do "git status src", it shows some files underneath src that are modified.  This is all from CLI.  Should i run "git add src" anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience with the exact same issue, the solution is to back up your entire repo by copying it somewhere safe, cloning the last 'good' commit from the origin into your working project directory, then adding changed files in incrementally, and committing as-needed until you get back to where you need to be. Based on the solution here: 
https://xkcd.com/1597/